# Catch 500 internal server error with System.WebClient

Tags: c#

I have some code that does `DownloadStringAsync`. with my brower i can get some information about the error since I turned on send error message to browser in IIS. I was wondering if it's possible to catch it in the code.

```
void Process( Job job )
{
   using( WebClient client = new WebClient() )
   {
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args ) =>
            DownloadStringCompleted(job,args);

        try
        {
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(job.url), job);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
   }
}

void DownloadStringCompleted(Job job, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs args)
{
   if( args.Error != null )
   {
       // How can i get the response ? Like 500 Internal Server Error
       // this_buggy_page.asp Line 100000
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `args.Error != null` it will likely contain an instance of `WebException`; if this is the case, then you can cast it to `WebException`, then access its `Response` property, which you can cast to `HttpWebResponse` (for HTTP calls), and from there you can get the headers / body / etc.

Comment: Thanks. More detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167913/webexception-when-reading-a-webexceptions-response-stream